# Import Select SQL query stored procedure using Entity Framework 4 in Asp.Net and C# Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, stored-procedures, asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework

I am trying to import a stored procedure using Entity Framework 4 in an Asp.Net MVC project using C#. But when I try to update the model into entity diagram (*.edmx), it will be updated into the Entity name.Store inside stored procedure folder.

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Sp_Feedback
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        f.User_Id, f.Over_All_Rating, f.Features_Liked,
        f.Features_Need_Improvement,
        f.Will_Recommend_Us, f.Customer_Service_Rating, f.Comments 
    FROM 
        Feedback f
END
```

In my stored procedure I have selected a few columns from the table (not all columns). So I need to add a new entity for model mapping to the table. Once entity is created and add scalar properties to the entity to specify exact name in the table which I need to retrieve through the stored procedure. At last I had to mapping the new entity property name to the exact table entity.

When you expand the expand the stored-procedure folder there is a imported stored procedure right click stored procedure select **Add Function Import** option and dialog open displays that "**Function Import Name**" and "**Stored Procedure Name**" is already detected from the stored procedure and there is another option which is "**Returns a Collection Of**"

It contains four option which are

1. None
2. Scalars
3. Complex
4. Entities

In the **Returns a Collection** option I had to select the entities option to select the newly created entities for the mapping the stored procedure retrieved columns, because I need to get the list of records from the table.

Once I finished build the project, I got an error which is there is "no key value" for the newly created entity while mapping to the table entity.

After that I added a scalar property name for key value to the newly entity to map to the table entity. Again I build the project I got another error which is both the entities have the same key value.

I need to import the Select query based stored procedure using Entity Framework 4.